# Create svelte component on every click

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to create new instances of the same component in svelte whenever a button or other action happens on the page, without having to make a list and {each} over them.
I just want to do something like `new Component(some context data)` and forget.
Another concern is I don't want the component to disappear when the parent is removed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mount it straight on the `document.body`:

```js
new Component({ target: document.body })
```

But be aware that if you do not [`$destroy`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$destroy) it yourself, you will end up with a memory leak.

When I do something like this, e.g. for notifications, I dispatch an event from the component that tells the calling code when the component can safely be destroyed. Something like:

```js
const notification = new Notification({ target: document.body, ... });
notification.$on('close', () => notification.$destroy());
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, I'm just wondering what happens when say the caller (parent) no longer exists when the event is fired, does it still destroy / clean up ?
Edit: my guess is yes, since the event is set to the notif itself right?

Comment: @LAZ: This will work without issue ([REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/32a01fd049d447f498b0021d7ffaf611?version=3.48.0)).

Comment: Oh, last thing, now that I've made a helper func to handle this behavior, I'm having trouble passing elements for the slots in the components. I know how to pass props, but nothing else really

Comment: Slots in the client-side API are currently not supported, there is a Github issues about that somewhere. I would probably just bind an element within the instantiated component and append to that instead. To access props directly, the component needs to be compiled with `<svelte:options accessors />`. ([REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b8e1d3cfcfc4f52b62ba187140fe4f3?version=3.48.0))

Comment: Ok thank you. I passed components as props and used `<svelte:component>` to instantiate them, works well enough for my needs.